# Saving webview geturl and getitle in Sqlite database. Problem with syntax error apostrophe '

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, sql-insert

When im saving webview.getTitle (); in Sqlite database, if in title has apostrophe ('), then i got error -

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "at": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Favorite VALUES('4 madhab bid'at tavassul', 'file:///android_asset/web/akaid/4maddhab/4.htm' );

My code like this

```
mysql objcon = new mysql(this, null, null, 1);
SQLiteDatabase db = objcon.getReadableDatabase();
db.execSQL(
    "INSERT INTO Favorite VALUES('"
     + txtnombre.getText()
     + "', '"
     + txtlink2.getText()
     +"' );"
);
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: by calling `db.insert(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a single quote embedded within `txtnombre.getText()` : `'4 madhab bid'at tavassul'`. This causes SQLite to wrongly consider that this quote marks the end of the first value to insert.

To avoid that, you could consider manually doubling the single quotes :

```
db.execSQL(
    "INSERT INTO Favorite VALUES('"
    + txtnombre.getText().replaceAll("'","\''")
    + "', '"
    + txtlink2.getText().replaceAll("'","\''")
    +"' );"
);
```

I would recommend using bind parameters. With this option, your database driver handles escaping behind the hood :

```
q = "INSERT INTO Favorite VALUES(?, ?)";
t1 = txtnombre.getText();
t2 = txtlink2.getText();
db.rawQuery(q, new String[] { t1, t2 });
```

Finally, another approach in Android would be to use native method [`sqlEscapeString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils#sqlEscapeString(java.lang.String), which is primarily built for this purpose.

Also, as commented by pskink, using [insert()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) would better fit your use case than raw SQL.

Comment: `rawQuery` is not meant for inserting new records - instead simply call `SQLiteDatabase#insert` method

Comment: @pskink : I updated my answer to mention that... Thanks !

Comment: I checked, thanks guys. The most nearly suited answer was for me `replaceAll` regex answer. `txtnombre` and `txtlink2` were EditTexts, so i used like this:
`db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Favorite VALUES('" 
+ txtnombre.getText().toString().replaceAll("'","\''")
+ "', '" 
+ txtlink2.getText().toString().replaceAll("'","\''") 
+ "' );" );`

Comment: @alizulfuqar `"The most nearly suited answer was for me replaceAll regex answer"` - no, just use `insert()` method - thats all - `execSQL` is not meant for inserting new data, see [execSql](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[])), the docs say: *"Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE."*

Comment: @pskink from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String): *Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data*. So it can be *INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE*

Comment: @pskink `INSERT` **does not return data**.  *couple of lines below* is referring to another overload of `execSql()` that is not the case here. The OP is not using `execSQL(String sql, Object[] bindArgs)` but `execSQL(String sql)`

Comment: The `INSERT` sql statement **does not return the id**, but the method `insert()`. Can you see the difference?

Comment: It is: *any other SQL statement that returns data* because the return type of exeSql is void.  The statements: `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` **do not return any data**.

Comment: Don't use a phrase from the documentation to cover your mistake. `exeSql()` **can** be used for `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`. It is only in the case of safety (sql injection) that you should avoid it and use insert(), update() or delete() methods. And once again `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` **do not return any data**. I'm done here.